# Trigonometric Limits function

Tags: limits, trigonometry

I need to find this limit

$\lim_{\theta\to \frac \pi2}$ (2 $\theta$ - $\pi$) sec $\theta$ ?

Comment: Note: $\cos \theta = \sin (\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta)$.

Comment: Also:  Around zero you have $\sin x\approx x$

Answer (score 1):

Set $2\theta-\pi=x$

$\displaystyle\implies x\to 0$  and  $\displaystyle\theta=\frac{\pi+x}2$

$$\implies\lim_{\theta\to\frac\pi2}(2\theta-\pi)\sec\theta=\lim_{x\to0}x\sec\frac{\pi+x}2=\lim_{x\to0}\frac x{\cos\frac{\pi+x}2}=-\lim_{x\to0}\frac x{\sin\frac x2}\  \ \ \ (1)$$ as $\cos(\frac\pi2+y)=-\sin y$

We know $\lim_{y\to0}\frac{\sin y}y=1$ so put $x=2y$ in $(1)$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $$\lim_{\theta \to \frac{\pi}{2}} (2\theta-\pi) \sec \theta = -2\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x}{\sin x}.$$

Comment: How did you get that -2 ?

Comment: $2\theta-\pi = -2\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2} - \theta\right)$ and $x := \dfrac{\pi}{2} - \theta$.